# rhn-client-tools

Tags: package-management, 20.04

I have an old box running Spacewalk as a registrationg/management server. Recently I've installed the Ubuntu Focal Fossa, but I cannot seem able to find the rhn-client-tools utility to register it.
Do you know if the package is available/supported for Focal?

Thank you very much

Comment: A quick searcvh gave me this link. Did you even try to search for the information. https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/rhn-client-tools

Comment: Hi David, yes I did looked that link, but it is applied to Xenial, not focal fossa, and it seems the package is not available for this version. Thank you

Comment: The package was removed - this was requested in this bug: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1737200 with the reason: "Please remove all the listed below packages (both source and binary) from the bionic archive. All packages are no longer actively maintained and have been requested to be removed from Debian as well (with rhn-client-tools, rhnsd, apt-spacewalka and python-xklavier already removed from testing). lxkeymap did not have a new update since over 4 years."

Comment: Basically, "Dead Software Is Dead" is why it was removed.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, very helpful. Do you have any experience in sw management for ubuntu? It seems foreman has some compatibility issues, and Landscape is paid when over 10 clients. pulp I don t know too much. It doesn t happen you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install it by manual package download from [16.04 LTS repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/rhn-client-tools):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/newt/libnewt0.52_0.52.18-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-dmidecode/python-dmidecode_3.12.2-2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-ethtool/python-ethtool_0.11-3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-gudev/python-gudev_147.2-3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/newt/python-newt_0.52.18-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rhnlib/python-rhn_2.5.55-2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rhn-client-tools/rhn-client-tools_1.8.26-4_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./rhn-client-tools_1.8.26-4_amd64.deb ./python-rhn_2.5.55-2_all.deb ./python-ethtool_0.11-3_amd64.deb ./python-newt_0.52.18-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-dmidecode_3.12.2-2_amd64.deb ./python-gudev_147.2-3_amd64.deb ./libnewt0.52_0.52.18-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

To prevent upgrade of `libnewt0.52` package you have to pin its version by single long command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-newt
Package: libnewt0.52
Pin: version 0.52.18-1ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

---

Note: to revert changes - remove the above file with `sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-newt` and upgrade all packages with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you very much Norbert, I will try that approach, basically we just have to make sure that libnewt is not upgraded, so I assume all the others are okay to upgrade from FF repos.

Answer (score 0):

content management for Ubuntu works well in Foreman/Katello today.
If you need an enterprise product you should have a look at orcharhino. orcharhino is the commercially supported downstream product of Foreman/Katello for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but from my investigation the last supported version  of ubuntu as platform is bionic. Were you able to install it on focal? Cheers

Comment: You cannot install Katello on Ubuntu. You need to use an EL7 based distro like CentOS for installation. After installation you can manage Ubuntu content including focal.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I do think I can install it on Ubuntu Bionic, not necessarily rhel based distros, I say that because I already have a proxy rule against ubuntu repos. So I think I will try to deploy foreman/katellos on bionic beaver. Lemme know if you see any issue.

Comment: Hi Mara, Katello depends on different products including pulp and candlepin. As far as I know there are no packaged versions for ubuntu for this.

Comment: Thanks Mark, already deployed a rhel7, as per foreman specs.